# How to search and replace in the entire buffer?

Tags: replace

Search and replace, by <kbd>M-%</kbd> and <kbd>!</kbd>, is done from current position to the end of the buffer. How can I do it for the entire buffer? Thanks.

Comment: I suggest changing the title to "search and replace entire buffer". Globally could also be referring to entire projects.

Comment: This is one area where Vim/Evil is hard to beat: `:%s/foo/bar`

Comment: @shosti: Actually, I think your method requires more keystrokes.  Just sayin' ;-)

Answer (score 17):

I don't see that supported while still retaining your starting position. (I don't see a way to wrap to the beginning of the buffer when search reaches the end.)

Your best bet is using <kbd>M-<</kbd> to go to the start of the buffer, then do the `query-replace`, when you're done press <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-space</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>C-space</kbd> to jump back to your starting point.

Comment: This works when `transient-mark-mode` is on.  Otherwise `C-SPC C-SPC` will temporarily enable `transient-mark-mode`

Comment: No need to set the mark manually with C-SPC. M-< (and many other commands that potentially "move point a long way") does it for you.

Answer (score 15):

You can follow the following steps:

- `C-x h` — Select the whole buffer *or* `M-<` - Go to the top of the buffer
- `M-%` — Initiate `query-replace`
- `!` — Force replace all
- `C-u C-SPC C-u C-SPC` — Move back to your starting position

Comment: This should get more attention.

Answer (score 9):

You could add the following command to your emacs initialization file, and bind it to
the keystroke of your choice.

```
(defun replace-regexp-entire-buffer (pattern replacement)
  "Perform regular-expression replacement throughout buffer."
  (interactive
   (let ((args (query-replace-read-args "Replace" t)))
     (setcdr (cdr args) nil)    ; remove third value returned from query---args
     args))
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (re-search-forward pattern nil t)
      (replace-match replacement))))
```

Comment: Can it iterate to replace each one by one?

Answer (score 3):

You can add this to your `init.el` file to update the behavior of `M-%` to to replace the word in the entire buffer by default:

```
(defun my/query-replace (from-string to-string &optional delimited start end)
  "Replace some occurrences of FROM-STRING with TO-STRING.  As each match is
found, the user must type a character saying what to do with it. This is a
modified version of the standard `query-replace' function in `replace.el',
This modified version defaults to operating on the entire buffer instead of
working only from POINT to the end of the buffer. For more information, see
the documentation of `query-replace'"
  (interactive
   (let ((common
      (query-replace-read-args
       (concat "Query replace"
           (if current-prefix-arg " word" "")
           (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) " in region" ""))
       nil)))
     (list (nth 0 common) (nth 1 common) (nth 2 common)
       (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
           (region-beginning)
         (buffer-end -1))
       (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
           (region-end)
         (buffer-end 1)))))
  (perform-replace from-string to-string t nil delimited nil nil start end))
;; Replace the default key mapping
(define-key esc-map "%" 'my/query-replace)
```

And to get the same behavior from `query-replace-regexp`:

```
(defun my/query-replace-regexp (regexp to-string &optional delimited start end)
  "Replace some things after point matching REGEXP with TO-STRING.  As each
match is found, the user must type a character saying what to do with
it. This is a modified version of the standard `query-replace-regexp'
function in `replace.el', This modified version defaults to operating on the
entire buffer instead of working only from POINT to the end of the
buffer. For more information, see the documentation of `query-replace-regexp'"
  (interactive
   (let ((common
      (query-replace-read-args
       (concat "Query replace"
           (if current-prefix-arg " word" "")
           " regexp"
           (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active) " in region" ""))
       t)))
     (list (nth 0 common) (nth 1 common) (nth 2 common)
       (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
           (region-beginning)
         (buffer-end -1))
       (if (and transient-mark-mode mark-active)
           (region-end)
         (buffer-end 1)))))
  (perform-replace regexp to-string t t delimited nil nil start end))
;; Replace the default key mapping
(define-key esc-map [?\C-%] 'my/query-replace-regexp)
```

Comment: Very useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you use [**Icicles**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can [search-and-replace](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search-And-Replace) over the entire buffer (or multiple buffers or files or bookmark targets).

And unlike `query-replace` (e.g. `C-x h M-%`):

- You can navigate the matches [in any order](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview).
- Replacement is on demand: you *need not visit each match* and answer whether or not to replace it.

Comment: `Icicles` link seems dead

Comment: @alper: Thanks; corrected. Emacs Wiki changed from http to https, and added an `emacs/` subdir.

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution I'm currently using, it start from the begining of the buffer and will go back to old point after replacing.

```
    (defun query-replace-region-or-from-top ()
      "If marked, query-replace for the region, else for the whole buffer (start from the top)"
      (interactive)
      (progn
        (let ((orig-point (point)))
          (if (use-region-p)
              (call-interactively 'query-replace)
            (save-excursion
              (goto-char (point-min))
              (call-interactively 'query-replace)))
          (message "Back to old point.")
          (goto-char orig-point))))
    (bind-key* "M-%" 'query-replace-region-or-from-top)
```

Comment: @alper Check the updated version, I personally never got any issue.

Comment: Would it be possible to make this case sensetive?

Comment: @alper use `(let ((case-fold-search nil))` check https://stackoverflow.com/a/5346418/1528712

Answer (score 1):

My very simple but effective variant, which just advises both `query-replace` and `query-replace-regexp` to start replacing from the top of the buffer if region is not active. Otherwise, replace in the region only.

So this doesn't need new keybinds - just continue to use <kbd>M-%</kbd> and <kbd>M-C-%</kbd>.

```
(defun jj/goto-top-if-no-region (orig-func &rest args)
  "if region is not active, go to the buffer start"
  (save-excursion
    (when (not (use-region-p))
      (goto-char (point-min)))
    (apply orig-func args)))

(advice-add 'query-replace :around #'jj/goto-top-if-no-region)
(advice-add 'query-replace-regexp :around #'jj/goto-top-if-no-region)
```