# frame-background-mode leads `Args out of range: #<buffer doo.py>, 0, 1` error

Tags: frames, colors, replace

I am using following [answer to search and replace a word in the entire buffer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50624/18414):

```
(defun query-replace-region-or-from-top ()
  "If marked, query-replace for the region, else for the whole buffer (start from the top)"
  (interactive)
  (progn
    (let ((orig-point (point)))
      (if (use-region-p)
          (call-interactively 'query-replace)
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (call-interactively 'query-replace)))
      (message "Back to old point.")
      (goto-char orig-point))))
```

In addition, when I add `(setq-default frame-background-mode 'dark)` line in my `.emacs` file, I have following error message when I use `query-replace-region-or-from-top` function:

```
`Args out of range: #<buffer doo.py>, 0, 1`
```

What my be the reason of this error and how can I resolve it?

---

Debuggin result:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (args-out-of-range #<buffer Driver.py> 0 1)
  buffer-substring-no-properties(0 1)
  perform-replace("DataStorage" "DataStorage" t nil nil nil nil nil nil nil nil)
  query-replace("DataStorage" "DataStorage" nil nil nil nil nil)
  funcall-interactively(query-replace "DataStorage" "DataStorage" nil nil nil nil nil)
  call-interactively(query-replace)
  (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (call-interactively (quote query-replace)))
  (if (use-region-p) (call-interactively (quote query-replace)) (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (call-interactively (quote query-replace))))
  (let ((orig-point (point))) (if (use-region-p) (call-interactively (quote query-replace)) (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (call-interactively (quote query-replace)))) (message "Back to old point.") (goto-char
orig-point))
  (progn (let ((orig-point (point))) (if (use-region-p) (call-interactively (quote query-replace)) (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (call-interactively (quote query-replace)))) (message "Back to old point.")
(goto-char orig-point)))
  query-replace-region-or-from-top()
  funcall-interactively(query-replace-region-or-from-top)
  call-interactively(query-replace-region-or-from-top nil nil)
  command-execute(query-replace-region-or-from-top)
```

Comment: In addition to the error message, you’ll need the back trace to find out _where_ the error happened. Run `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` then reproduce the problem again.

Comment: @db48x Please see my updated questions along with the debugging result, hope it helps.

Comment: Does the problem occur when you start emacs from `emacs -Q`?

Comment: No seems like it works . Than some other setting in my `.emacs` file may be the main cause of this problem. It is pretty difficult to find the reason in thousands line of `.emacs` code

Comment: Yes, it is. But Emacs' commenting functions make it much easier to bisect your init to locate the problem https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28429/how-do-i-troubleshoot-emacs-problems?r=SearchResults

Comment: It was related to theme I was loading => `(load-theme 'dracula t)` // https://github.com/dracula/emacs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using [dracula-theme](https://github.com/dracula/emacs) `(load-theme 'dracula t)`, which was the main cause of the error I was facing.

When I use `query-replace-region-or-from-top` function along with dracula-theme and `(setq-default frame-background-mode 'dark)` I was facing the error I mention on my question.

```
(defun query-replace-region-or-from-top () ... ;; function from my question
(load-theme 'dracula t)
(setq-default frame-background-mode 'dark)
```

First, I have removed `(setq-default frame-background-mode 'dark)` from my `.init` file. The reason, I wanted to use `(setq-default frame-background-mode 'dark)` was to make highlights clear to read. Due to dracula-theme it was so lights and during word seach font color gets white.

---

In order to achieve this, I have update settings for `Isearch` and `Lazy Highlight` using `M-x customize-face`.

[image]

[image]

Following lines are added into my `customize.el` file:

```
(custom-set-faces
 '(isearch ((t :background "#f1fa8c" :foreground "#282a36" :weight bold)))
 '(lazy-highlight ((t :background "#8be9fd" :foreground "#282a36" :weight bold)))))
```