# How can I replace all in symbol manner?

Tags: replace, isearch, query-replace

I am using following solution ([How do I add a keybinding to use during an interactive isearch, `C-s ...`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/55306/how-do-i-add-a-keybinding-to-use-during-an-interactive-isearch-c-s)) to move over symbols in the buffer, which iterates over the matching symbols:

```lisp
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-w")
  'isearch-forward-symbol-at-point)
```

Is it possible to apply same manner into replace-all where instead of text it replaces the symbols (where the `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` iterates over):

My [query replace function](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/50624/18414), which replace all the matching query instead of only the symbols:

```lisp
(defun query-replace-region-or-from-top ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (progn
      (let ((orig-point (point)))
        (if (use-region-p)
            (call-interactively 'query-replace)
          (save-excursion
            (goto-char (point-min))
            (call-interactively 'query-replace)))
        (message "Back to old point.")
        (goto-char orig-point)))))

(global-set-key "\C-x\C-r"  'query-replace-region-or-from-top)
```

---

**Example_1:**

```python
gas_costs = 100
_cost = 10
log(f"==> cost={_cost}")
```

Replace-all `_cost` into `cost`

=> changes into:

```python
gascosts = 100
cost = 10
log(f"==> cost={cost}")
```

wanted:

```python
gas_cost = 100  # should remain unchanged
cost = 100
log(f"==> cost={cost}")
```

---

**Example_2:**

```python
alper = 100
alper99 = 99
```

Replace-all `alper` into `sad`

=> changes into:

```python
sad = 100
sad99 = 99
```

wanted:

```python
sad = 100
alper99 = 99
```

---

I just want to replace patterns as exactly same with `isearch` finds. Because first I always search patterns using `isearch` and than replace them. But if there are diffierent matched patterns in `replace-all`, I get end up replacing differect results than `isearch` finds.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT in response to the question in your comment

To use the regexp pattern as a default in your function, you could use the following code (note that here I have also somewhat improved the regexp and replace patterns):

```lisp
(defun query-replace-region-or-from-top (pattern &optional beg end)
  (interactive "sEnter symbol: \nr")
  (let ((case-fold-search nil)
        (regexp (concat "\\([[:blank:]{]\\|^\\)" pattern)))
    (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-min))
      (apply #'query-replace-regexp
             regexp
             (concat "\\1" (substring pattern 1))
             nil
             (when (use-region-p)
               (list beg end))))))
```

Note that I have also added the default replace pattern, which is the pattern minus the starting `_`. If you don't want that, then you could ask for a second string in the `interactive` form, and use that for the replacement pattern. Or you could only ask for the replacement pattern and automatically 'compose' the regexp pattern. Of course, I don't know your exact use case(s).

END EDIT

From your explanation, it is not clear to me what you are asking exactly (e.g. what is replace-all). But it looks to me that the answer to your 'main' question is that you are actually looking for `(query-)replace-regexp`.

E.g. to solve the problem of your example, you can use `query-replace-regexp` using the following [regexp](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html) `\([[:space:]{]\|^\)+_cost` (and replace with `cost`).

Some comments about your function:

- the `progn` is redundant, as you are already within a `let` (and so the second `let` is also redundant).
- you are setting the `orig-point` and jump back to it, while you are also using `save-excursion` within. So to me, the `save-excursion` looks ineffective. To get the same effect, you can just wrap the whole `if` in `save-excursion`.

However, maybe you want something like the following:

```lisp
(defun query-replace-region-or-from-top (&optional mark)
  (interactive "m")
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (cond ((use-region-p)
           (call-interactively 'query-replace-regexp)
           (goto-char (min region)))
          (t
           (save-excursion
             (goto-char (point-min))
             (call-interactively 'query-replace-regexp))))))
```

You could alternatively use the [interactive code](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Interactive-Codes.html#index-region-argument) `r`, if you would like to jump back to either the beginning or the end of your region.

Comment: Ah `replace-all` is not correct way to put it. I just wanted to search and replace in the entire buffer starting from first appearance in the buffer till end. When I tried your solution it replaces the `_cost` int `gas_cost` which I don't want

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you have tried, but with the regexp pattern I provided, the `_cost` in `gas_cost` should not get replaced, and it works like expected here. I am sure that the pattern is correct. Please try again, maybe using `emacs -Q`

Comment: Let me try with a empty file ; I put to end of my init file maybe something was preventing it to work as it should be

Comment: It does not work with `emacs -Q` changin `gas_cost` into `gascost` :-(

Comment: You should use the pattern `\([[:space:]{]\|^\)+_cost` (copy-paste it) after doing `M-x query-replace-region-or-from-top` (the version I've posted here). Otherwise, I am not sure what kind of Emacs you are using ;)

Comment: Could this pattern `\([[:space:]{]\|^\)+_cost` embedded into the function and act as its default behavior? Like if I give `_cost` , the function convert it into the pattern

Comment: Of course it can. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot . .

Comment: 2nd solution does not generated wanted changes, and changes gas_costs to gascosts. The first solution does not ask what to changed with as interactive input and also it does not apply changes to complete buffer by default, when I try to apply  `query-replace-region-or-from-top` generates: `The mark is not set now, so there is no region `. Is it possible to select the region as complete buffer by default and ask what to replace with?

Comment: `_cost` => `cost` was just an example, it can be `_cost` => `emacs123` or anything. I just wanted apply replace operation to replace matches same as the find words/patterns in `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point`

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your questions: 'select the region as complete buffer by default' and 'apply replace operation to replace matches same as the find words/patterns in isearch-forward-symbol-at-point'. I do not understand those...

Comment: When you try following solution it iterates from top of the buffer to down to apply replace https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/249/how-to-search-and-replace-in-the-entire-buffer/50624#50624 (which is also in my question)// and in `isearch-forward-symbol-at-point` when you search for `_cost` it does not found `_cost` in the `gas_cost` since it search for the words

Comment: I have also added another example related to this

Comment: You should have a look at [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Backslash.html) and [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/emacs-regular-expression-syntax.html), especially the `\b`, `\<` and `\_<`. Then practice a little/do some tests using `replace-regexp` or `regexp-builder`.

Comment: I am not experienced in writing lisp language and its difficult for me to understand and debug. The question I asked should be straight to point where I just want to replace patterns as word same as `isearch` finds. Because first I always search patterns in `isearch` and than replace them but hence all diffierent matched patterns also changed in replace-all